# can i use with clause in jdbc prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, with-clause

Is it possible to run a prepared statement in jdbc that uses with clause in a single sql statement something like this

```
public class JdbcSample {
    private static  String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:demoapp:v2://localhost:8080";
    private static List<ResultSet> resultSets = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting the app.");
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        testPreparedQuery(connection);

    }

public static void testPreparedQuery(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String preparedSql = "with temp as (select * from nation where col1 = ?) select * from temp";

        PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement(preparedSql);
        pStmt.setString(1,"india");

        ResultSet resultSet = pStmt.executeQuery();

        resultSet.next();

    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        AsgardDriver.registerDriver();

        Driver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(jdbcUrl);
        Properties props = new Properties();

        Connection connection = driver.connect(jdbcUrl, props);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

when I tried to run this its throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I tried multiple sqls none of them works. I went through docs but didn't find any evidence about whether we can use with clause or not in the prepared statement.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `with` but you can't parameterize column names in a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: What is `pStmt`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Stream_Cipher the answer to your question is 'yes'. The NPE you are witnessing is not related to the problem you think it is related to. You'd have to paste a lot more to figure it out. For example, where `pStmt` is defined.

Comment: you posted, kind of hidden, `prepareStatement(preparedSql)` (assuming the missing semi-colon `;` is a copy&paste error), but code is setting `sql` instead of `preparedSql`? Another copy&paste error? || Maybe I am a bit *strange*, but I would never be *satisfied* making such a formatted post, specially if asking for help...

Comment: i have added a complete code snippet that I am using to run the query for my app , 
sorry for the incomplete question summary 
i would be happy to share any further information

Comment: usually the stack trace also shows where - which code line and file - the exception is being thrown. That helps finding out what is `null` (modern Java versions also show that in the NullPointerException message.)

Comment: You should be using `DriverManager.getConnection`, not `DriverManager.getDriver` and then `Driver.connect`. It is entirely possible that `getDriver` selected a driver which on further parsing of the URL will return `null` instead of throwing an exception. However, I think it is unlikely that `jdbc:demoapp:v2:` is a valid JDBC prefix though, and that would cause an exception in `getDriver`. In other words, you really need to provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. Also, what is the `AsgardDriver`? If it is a custom JDBC driver, then maybe it returns `null` somewhere.